# Visual Studio 2010 runtime check failure # 3

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010, coding-style, runtime

It looks like that Microsoft is backfiring again in VS2010. Here's my code

```
#include "string.h"
typedef struct s_test
{
    unsigned char a[20];
} t_test, *p_test;
void initialize(t_test t)
{
    memset(t.a, 0, 20);
}
void main()
{
    t_test t;
    initialize(t);
}
```

and it throws

```
Run-Time Check Failure #3 - The variable 't' is being used without being initialized.
```

Well...since in other cases the runtime checker does help so I'm less likely to turn it off in the solution. But how the hell should I do with this? You might suggest to change the way the argument is passed to pointers. However it would be an unpleasant experience regarding a consistent coding style. Now I feel like rawring to MS for this BRILLIANT stuff ;p

Comment: Your code doesn't compile.  There is no member `a` in `t_test`

Comment: Thanks Jared correction is made.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the error report you are getting is a perfectly valid and appropriate error report. This is exactly what you are doing: you are using an uninitialized value. You are attempting to copy an uninitialized object - in which case the report from tun-time checker is, of course, expected.

Basically, what you are doing in your code is equivalent to this

```
int a, b = a;
```

This code will trigger the same error for the very same reason. So, why are you complaining about it?

Comment: I'm just feeling obsessed. In your example, any change of b in value wouldn't do same to a. So a is still uninitialized after that evaluation. I think that's the difference.

Comment: @Y.Z: I don't understand you point. In your code any change to the local `t` inside `initialize` will not change `t` passed from `main`. So, after `initialize` the `t` in `main` is still uninitialized. This is exactly and precisely the same as in my example. Where do you see the difference?

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're passing t by value - an unitialized value. Define your initialize function as follows, so that it can actually modify the passed in object and all is well:

```
void initialize(t_test *pt) 
{
    memset(pt->x, 0, 20); // x not a
}
```

Also, for the sake of all that's holy, change:

```
void main()
```

to

```
int main()
```

Comment: Correct, but C does not have references, only pointers.  You need to declare it as `void initialize(t_test *t)` and pass it as `initialize(&t)`.

Comment: @Adam, thanks for pointing out that the author asked about a C program. I modified my answer to reflect the fact that the question was about C, not C++.

Comment: Alright so it's not supposed to initialize local variable of main() in its sub-function, initialize() here, even if the local variable is still in its scope. That's just weird.

Comment: @Y.Z: How's that "weird"? You explicitly asked the compiler to create a copy of the original (uninitialized) `t` and then you initialized that copy. I think it is perfectly logical that the original `t` remained uninitialized in this case. Noting weird here.